# MySQL Delete Distinct - IE Keep any duplicate delete unique

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

Hi all first time poster but have had some great ideas from people on this platform before.
Just learning and starting to use MySQL for  large database and have found an issue I cannot find an answer for on how to do this.

I have a table structure as below:

```
|dt|ID|Location ID|
|--|--|-----------|
|21/03/2021 10:57:12|ab123|1234|
|21/03/2021 10:57:12|ab127|19826|
|21/03/2021 10:57:12|ab123|1721|
|21/03/2021 10:57:12|ab124|7656|
|21/03/2021 10:57:12|ab130|1001|
|21/03/2021 10:57:12|ab335|1991|
|21/03/2021 10:57:12|ab123|0010|
```

What I would like to do is remove all entries that have a single ID that matches. In essence delete any distinct ID's.

So this would return:

```
|dt|ID|Location ID|
|--|--|-----------|
|21/03/2021 10:57:12|ab123|1234|
|21/03/2021 10:57:12|ab123|1721|
|21/03/2021 10:57:12|ab123|0010|
```

The command DELETE(Distinct 'ID') from table; would be ideally what I want to do but this isn't valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subselect to get the ID that should be deleted

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`dt` varchar(19), `ID` varchar(5), `Location ID` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`dt`, `ID`, `Location ID`)
> VALUES
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab123', 1234),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab127', 19826),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab123', 1721),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab124', 7656),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab130', 1001),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab335', 1991),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab123', 0010)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (seLECt `ID` FROM (SELECT ID FROM table1) t1  GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> dt                  | ID    | Location ID
> :------------------ | :---- | ----------:
> 21/03/2021 10:57:12 | ab123 |        1234
> 21/03/2021 10:57:12 | ab123 |        1721
> 21/03/2021 10:57:12 | ab123 |          10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cff624998e8883a67122d3659b042528)*

This version with `inner join`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`dt` varchar(19), `ID` varchar(5), `Location ID` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`dt`, `ID`, `Location ID`)
> VALUES
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab123', 1234),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab127', 19826),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab123', 1721),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab124', 7656),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab130', 1001),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab335', 1991),
>     ('21/03/2021 10:57:12', 'ab123', 0010)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> DELETE table1 FROM table1
>         INNER JOIN  (seLECt `ID` FROM (SELECT ID FROM table1) t1  GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) t1
>      ON table1.ID = t1.ID 
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> dt                  | ID    | Location ID
> :------------------ | :---- | ----------:
> 21/03/2021 10:57:12 | ab123 |        1234
> 21/03/2021 10:57:12 | ab123 |        1721
> 21/03/2021 10:57:12 | ab123 |          10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7eae95d8c96df33d94bdc384ebca4bfa)*

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response. this works great but not on a large table which I didn't mention. The table has 50+ million rows and this command will hopefully delete 14 million. Unfortunately due to the size it seems to just lock up and I cancelled it after several hours? Any ideas for a large table?

Comment: that a lot of rows.  i added a inner join version, this has advatages wuthbbig tabole, when you have also big joined buffer in yout my.conf. else split the table in smaller parts and run the partitions.  Finding doubles costs time deleting also

Comment: Takes 25 minutes to run but works, thank you :)